Bootstrap nav bar dropdown background color overlaps div

I have implemented a Bootstrap nav bar on my homepage that has some dropdown elements.
When I open the dropdown menu the :hover/:focus background-color overlaps the dropdown div.
HTML:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Haus
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'ferienwohnung-oben' %}">Obere Ferienwohnung</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'ferienwohnung-unten' %}">Untere Ferienwohnung</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'haus' %}">Gesamtes Haus</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'hausregeln' %}">Hausregeln</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'anfahrt' %}">Anfahrt</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

CSS:
.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: #cbc0d3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

I have tried different overflow-x properties but none of them worked, and have not found a proper match of the issue here on Stack Overflow. Can anybody help out?

You adjusted the font weight .. so it changed the text size, perhaps remove the bold tag (font-weight:bold)?

You might be able to add this tag to the CSS as well :
box-sizing: border-box; to try to get it to stay in the box.  Let me know if any of this helps and I will type up a full answer.  You might be able to use a flex-box as well, but curious to see if any of this helps first.

Hi,
thanks for your advice! The ideas did not work, but I found out what the issue was in the meantime: It's the nav a {margin: 0 0.5rem;}.

Ahh didn't see that in the code you posted, but glad you fixed it there!
